# How do I make PyInstaller bundle Tcl/Tk for OSX targets? - Import Error Tcl/Tk modules not found - Pyinstaller on Mac is not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6, pyinstaller, macos-high-sierra

I have a frustrating problem that set me back a day trying to get an executable file from my finished bookstore app.

I used the `Pyinstaller --onefile --windowed bookstore.py`  from the main project menu, also `vm/bin/Pyinstaller --onefile --windowed bookstore.py` which created the `.exe` and `.app` file successfully.

HOWEVER, when running the `.app` file, nothing happens. It starts, and just disappears.

I ran the core executable from the cli on Mac from the main project folder with `open dist/bookstore.app/Contents/Macos/bookstore` and, loads of research and over 20 variations of code and file changes later, I got the same same trackback (N.B. different file path for global `Pyinstaller`) error message back from the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bookstore.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/Users/jmulhall/Documents/Documents/Python_Project_Folder/Python3_Training/ProjectBookstore/vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/Users/jmulhall/Documents/Documents/Python_Project_Folder/Python3_Training/ProjectBookstore/vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/0d/6l_1mgwn4cxbrx21_nm7l8gh0000gn/T/_MEIHyYK9G/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/Tcl
  Referenced from: /var/folders/0d/6l_1mgwn4cxbrx21_nm7l8gh0000gn/T/_MEIHyYK9G/_tkinter.so
  Reason: image not found
[3899] Failed to execute script bookstore
```

My Mac details are as follows:

```
MacOs High Sierra V 10.13.3  with a standard HD on a mid 2012 Macbook Pro
```

My Software versions are `python 3.6.4`, `pyinstaller 3.3.1` , `virtualenv 15.1.0`, `sqllite3 3.19.3`

The most promsing fix on github did not work ergo my query on fixing the Pyinstaller issue for mac where it loads the tcl and tk resources. The links I followed are here:​

[Main Query Link - Github​](https://github.com/viotti/pyinstaller/commit/597af5cb01c064620b53ea1ee537e30f56fa481d#comments),

[Support File Changes Demo for hooks​](https://github.com/miguelHx/pyinstaller/commit/e56a46dcc795ec271644d1852deb53be6a6cd9db)

I created a `pyinstaller-hooks` folder and inserted the hook and pyruntime hooks file into the folder with the `tclResources` and `tkResources` name changes in the files as follows:

[image: hook-_tkinter.py file change from tk/tcl to tkResources/tclResources]

[image: pyi_rth__tkinter.py file change from tk/tcl to tkResources/tclResources]

This did not work.

And I am still getting the above stack trace despite running the new command, picking up the new pyinstaller-hooks folder files in the main project folder, as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --additional-hooks-dir pyinstaller-
hooks --runtime-hook pyinstaller-hooks/pyi_rth__tkinter.py bookstore.py
```

Why is it still not finding the the new files with `Tree()` and `os.path.join())` functions altered to tkResources/tclResources and thus crashing the app when it tries to launch. I could not test the `.exe` as I have only a Mac environment so Im only focused on the `.app` right now. Can anybody help with this?

Nearly forgot, my main project folder view is as follows:

[image: Main Project Folder View]

Comment: Does it work without windowed mode? I am curious as this is more a problem with windows but could be with mac.  Most likely is not, but still might be worth a try.  On second thought looks like that is not being imported correctly

Comment: Yes, works without the —windowed perimeter in producing an .exe’s but I could not test it as I was not on windows. The stack trace points consistently to an Import error around the tcl module and tkinter.so not found.

Comment: Rather than use cmd for imports maybe try manually importing it in the spec file itself and see if error message changes at all.    If that doesn't work, submit a bug on pyinstaller.

Comment: I tried it but it came up with the same traceback when I tried to open the executable with 'open dist/bookstore.app/Contents/MacOS/bookstore'

Comment: Posted a comment in an open tick on github relating to the issue.. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1350 ... not sure if I should be opening a duplicate? Any advise on this is also appreciated..